# Is there any way to edit the metadata attributes of a video with python? (mov, mp4, etc.)

Tags: python, video, package, metadata

I am trying to create a script that allows me to edit the fields contained within the video metadata.

I am able to open the file with the MediaInfo library, but I am unable to save the edit to the video metadata.

Can anyone recommend a py library that allows me to read and edit the metadata of a video?

This is my code:

```
from pprint import pprint
from pymediainfo import MediaInfo

def main():
    mi = MediaInfo.parse("Video/video.mp4")
    metadata = mi.to_data()
    metadata["tracks"][0]["recorded_date"] = metadata["tracks"][0]["file_creation_date"]

main()
```

Thank you all in advance.

I have tried using the mutagen library, its problem is that it can only return me the filename and no other attributes.

I tried several libraries but they can only read the metadata but not edit it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [PyExifTool](https://github.com/sylikc/pyexiftool), which is a wrapper for [ExifTool](https://exiftool.org/), which would have to be installed separately.  ExifTool can edit a lot of metadata in MP4/Mov files (see the [ExifTool Quicktime tags page](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/QuickTime.html), specifically the `ItemList`, `UserData`, and `Keys` sections).

Comment: If you want to edit MKVs, you would need a different library, probably one based upon ffmpeg.